# onCreateView "calls itself"

Tags: android

I am trying to start up an application with 2 fragments, a row of buttons and a List Fragment but when I start it up the application's onCreateView gets called, calls getLayoutInflator to get a Layout Inflator. This in turn calls inflate, being passed int the name of the root layout file. Inside this code onCreateView gets called AGAIN, resulting in infinite recursion. Here is the code

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView, name = " + name + " context " + context + " AttributeSet = " + attrSet);
    View v = null; //super.onCreateView(name, context, attrSet);
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_shop2_drop,null);
        Log.i(TAG,"passed to LayoutInflater: " + R.layout.activity_shop2_drop);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `activity_shop2_drop` file?

Comment: I suppose you want to override `Fragment.onCreateView` instead of `Activity.onCreateView`

Comment: I tried to show my xml file, but the StackOverflow tool wouldn't let me, for some reason. In any case, I think I have figured this out: onCreateView DOES call itself for child layouts. I was simply not patient enough to step through it often enough to get back to the root view, and hence find the end of the function. I'm a victim of trying to assiduously to follow what's going on.

Comment: @vmironov does have it substantially correct; Fragment.onCreateView IS where I needed to put code that creates the Fragment's layout. However, now I have a different problem: it never gets to Fragment.onCreateView because the main layout fails when it encounters the "fragment" tag. I can get around that by not using the "fragment" tag, but everyone does, so it must be possible. Where is the "fragment" tag defined so I can make sure I have it in my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I called Fragment.onCreateView passing in the id of the containing view. This containing view was the view itself, so naturally the code tried to attach my code to what it thought was the containing view, which was itself. Hence the infinite recursion. A different problem is that the inflation code returns a ClassNotFoundException when it sees the "fragment" tag in activity_shop2_drop.xml and consequently never calls "onCreateView" on the fragment. I haven't solved this yet. Here is the activity_shop2_drop.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/whole_app_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        class="com.victorpreston.shop2drop.S2DButtonFragment"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFragmetLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <fragment
        class="com.victorpreston.shop2drop.S2DListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is thebutton_fragment_layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newItemButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/newColumnButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newColumnButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/newItemButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/exitButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note that they both create and use the same id. I tried changing that and it made no difference so I don't think that's the problem.